# Add text to the left of a v-data-table footer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, vuetifyjs3, v-data-table

I am using a v-data-table to display items that are due each day and a corresponding colored dot icon. I want to add a key in the footer showing what each color means (Overdue, Due Today, or Upcoming). Right now I am using this code:

```
<v-data-table :items="reports">
  <template v-slot:item="{item}">
    ... More Code Here ...
  </template>
  <template v-slot:footer.page-text>
    <div>
      <v-icon color="secondary" size="15px" style="margin-bottom:3px;">circle</v-icon> Upcoming
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <v-icon color="amber" size="15px" style="margin-bottom:3px;">circle</v-icon> Due Today
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <v-icon color="red" size="15px" style="margin-bottom:3px;">circle</v-icon> Overdue
    </div>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

But this displays the key in between buttons on the right side, like this:
[image: color key on the right (incorrect)]
Is there any way to make the key show up on the left side of the footer?
[image: desired color key location]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [v-slot:footer.prepend](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-footer.prepend)

> Adds content to the empty space in the footer

```html
<template v-slot:footer.prepend>
 ...
</template>
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/KKbOZwE?editors=1010)

Comment: This solved it. Thank you!